# Creating eos token using eos studio

Tags: eosio.token, tutorial

[image]I have done my research. All I found is people recommending me to use [eosio.token](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/tree/master/contracts/eosio.token) to create a eos token. The issue is it won't load in eos studio. I am just wondering is there any tutorials (preferably video) on the subject.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GgwBb2DY0bQ <--- won't work with eos studio

https://github.com/filipmartinsson/eos/tree/master/currency <—-is this template dated?

Comment: Be sure to accept given answers if they properly address your issue. This makes the question/answer easier for others to find in the future.

Answer (score 0):

EOS Studio is issuing the command you see in the output:

`eosio-cpp -abigen -I include -R resource -contract eos.token -o eos.token.wasm`

You should edit the **"Custom build command"** section to be something like:

`eosio-cpp -abigen -I include -R resource -contract eos.token -o eos.token.wasm src/eosio.token.cpp`

You may have to alter the `src/eosio.token.cpp` to your environment.

*(The hint to this is the error message telling you at least **1 positional argument** is required.)*

Comment: I am just wondering where do I send the parameter for the token such as its name?

Comment: The answer to solve this specific error with compiling is above. It requires a single positional argument for the source file. If that answers your original question please accept this one and create a new issue for any different errors.

Comment: I am just wondering where do I send the parameter for the token such as its name?

Comment: I'm not following you exactly. I said you need to edit the "custom build command" section and add the code I put above. Notice how my example adds `src/eosio.token.cpp` to the command?

Comment: Now I can compile. My second issue is how to I change the parameter for the token like the name and the number of tokens issued

Comment: As that is a new question entirely, please accept this answer if it satisfies your need and ask a new question.

Comment: I don't know how to accept the answer

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/473671